# Alternatives to Membrr add-on?

Tags: add-on, payment-gateway, subscriptions, membrr

We have been users of Membrr and OpenGateway for a few years now and been generally happy with it. Today I ran into an issue and went to access the http://www.membrr.com site and got a notice that the domain has expired. There have recently been reports that Electric Function has been unresponsive to emails and support. Concerned I started to do some Googling and found [this blog post from Brock](http://www.brockferguson.com/blog/my_relationship_with_electric_function) made back in March. Looks like the new owners of Electric Function might be simply dropping the company and products and walking away? As a customer I was not warned or notified at all and I find this very disturbing to say the least. Is anyone else who is using Membrr concerned? What path(s) are you planning on taking moving forward?

For anyone who was a Membrr user and migrated to something else what do you recommend and do you have any advice to make transitioning easier?

Comment: Yep I just recently started using Membrr/OG and this is quite disturbing. I hope it works flawlessly for me because I have the feeling there will never be any kind of support again.

Comment: Good news is that they have released the source code for Membrr, Open Gateway, and Donations. You can find them on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/electricfunction)

Comment: Membrr is here now: https://github.com/brockf/membrr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the developer of [Charge](http://squarebit.co.uk/addons/charge) so this is obviously biased.

Charge works great for member subscriptions. The focus with Charge is to keep it as simple and rock solid for the developer and customer as possible. To that end - it's tied directly to using Stripe as the payment gateway. Understandably that's not going to be perfect for every project.

I'm in the process of adding lots of new subscription features, and it's in constant development. I've helped quite a few devs move their client sites off Membrr to Charge, and keeping the whole thing invisible to the customers. If you need a hand, or see any missing features, just drop me a line, and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Any plan to add other gateways to Charge? I'm outside the US so can't use Stripe. Using PayPal at the moment with Membrr/OG.

Comment: I've got a few things in the works for other gateways. The exact implementation is the issue. Membrr and Cartthrob's issues all stem from trying to support all manner of gateways and all the complexity and extra bloat that needs.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are only 2 subscription modules that I know that you could transition to now that it looks like Membrr/OpenGateway are no longer going to be supported. Both options require a fair bit of work from you to handle the migration of content and subscriptions over but are probably better options then keeping a dead piece of software running your e-commerce site.

The first option would be to use [Charge](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/charge) by Joel Bradbury which is a great little piece of software. Charge relies on Stripe to be used as your payment gateway which can be a problem for some people but if you are able to use [Stripe](https://stripe.com) then Charge would be my recommendation. (I am currently in the process of moving a Membrr site over to charge myself.)

The other option would be to use [CartThrob](http://cartthrob.com/) and [CartThrob Subscriptions](http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_subscriptions/). CartThrob has a ton of additional gateways that you can use if you are not able to use Stripe and is a very full featured e-commerce solution.

Both options have their advantages and disadvantages so it is best to take a look at each and decide which is best for you project.

Comment: Just a note that CT Subs is no longer available for sale, though frankly they've done a pretty poor job of publicising that, and the website docs have not been fully updated to reflect this either.

Comment: I did not know that they were no longer selling it. Looks like Charge is the only option these days.

Comment: Hi Justin, if you don't mind and have time... would you mind outlining the basic steps for moving members from membrr to Stripe please?